# Comentar código y claridez del mismo

Tags: java

Primeramente aclarar que efectivamente me he leído varias guías de estilo antes de venir aquí. Me he asegurado de hacer un buen código pero quiero opiniones de terceros porque no sería la primera vez que creo hacer algo bien y resulta ser un desastre.

Esta no es una pregunta sobre algorísmica, en principio el programa que he creado funciona perfectamente **(Si de casualidad ves un fallo agradecería mucho un aviso**, aunque he hecho varías pruebas con inputs variadas y todo OK). Pero me surgen dudas sobre si a nivel de código éste se encuentra bien documentado. Es para un trabajo de la universidad con un relativamente elevado peso en la nota y me gustaría leer opiniones de terceras personas, igualmente tengo varias dudas concretas. Explicaré un poco de qué va el programa.

Debo implementar una interfaz `Conjunto` con una tabla de enteros mediante la clase `ConjuntoTabla`. Tanto la interfaz como el programa principal `TestConjuntoTabla` me vienen dados y no pueden ser modificados. No puedo usar tipos genéricos ni nada de la API de Java, debo crear todos los algoritmos.

Todas mis dudas son referidas a la clase `ConjuntoTabla`, que es la que yo he creado:

- ¿Es correcto el uso de setters y getters que hago dentro de la propia clase? O por el contrario debería acceder y modificar el atributo `_tablaInt` directamente dentro de las funciones?. De mantenerse, ¿deberían ser del tipo `static` o están bien así?
- ¿Es correcto el uso de una variable llamada `aux` para hacer los castings? ¿Hay alguna forma más 'elegante' de hacerlo o así es correcto?
- En este caso en particular no se usan los getters y setters fuera de la clase. Deben ser `public` o `private` (en caso de mantenerse)?
- Cuando implemento las funciones `union`, `interseccion`, `diferencia` uso algunas propiedades sencillas del conjunto vacío para agilizar un poco el rendimiento en el caso que alguna de las entradas sea el conjunto vacío. ¿Debería comentarlo o es lo suficientemente intuitivo para que no lo haga?
- He abusado bastante del término `this`, pero porque estoy empezando y quiero tener las ideas claras. ¿Puede ser que haya hecho algún uso totalmente absurdo del mismo en alguna parte del código?
- ¿Hay alguna parte del código que no se entienda y que deba ser comentada?

Dejo a continuación mi implementación de dicha clase, más abajo facilitaré tanto la interfaz como el main por si alguien quiere consultarlos:

```
public class ConjuntoTabla implements Conjunto {
//Descripción general: Implementación en forma de tabla de enteros

private int _tablaInt[];

/*Tabla de enteros ordenada de forma creciente
La longitud de la tabla siempre coincide con el número de
elementos del conjunto que representa */

public ConjuntoTabla() {
    this._tablaInt = new int [0];
}

public void setElem(int i, int n) {
   this. _tablaInt[i] = n;
}

public int getElem(int i) {
    return this._tablaInt[i];
}

//Se ha añadido n al conjunto ordenadamente
public void añadir(int n) {
    if (!this.pertenece(n)) {
        int i = this.nelem();
        int aux[] = new int[i+1];
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            aux[j] = getElem(j);
        }
        while (i > 0 && n < getElem(i-1)) {
            aux[i] = getElem(i-1);
            i--;
        }
        aux[i] = n;
        _tablaInt = aux;
}


public boolean pertenece(int n) {
    int medio, izq = 0, der = this.nelem()-1;
    boolean encontrado = false;
    while (!encontrado && izq <= der) {
        medio = (izq + der)/2;
        if (n < getElem(medio)) der = medio -1;
        else if (n > getElem(medio)) izq = medio + 1;
        else encontrado = true;
    }
    return encontrado;
}

public boolean vacio() {
    return (this.nelem() == 0);
}

public Conjunto union(Conjunto c) {
    ConjuntoTabla aux;
    aux = (ConjuntoTabla)c;
    if (aux.vacio()) return this;
    else if (this.vacio()) return c;
    else {
        ConjuntoTabla union = new ConjuntoTabla();
        for (int i=0; i < this.nelem(); i++) {
            union.añadir(getElem(i));
        }
        for (int i=0; i < c.nelem(); i++) {
            union.añadir(aux.getElem(i));
        }
    return union;
    }
}

public Conjunto interseccion(Conjunto c) {
    ConjuntoTabla interseccion = new ConjuntoTabla();
    ConjuntoTabla aux;
    aux = (ConjuntoTabla)c;
    if (!this.vacio() && !aux.vacio()) {
        for (int i=0; i < this.nelem(); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < aux.nelem(); j++) {
                int n = this.getElem(i);
                if (n==aux.getElem(j)) {
                    interseccion.añadir(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return interseccion;
}

public Conjunto diferencia(Conjunto c) {
    ConjuntoTabla diferencia = new ConjunoTabla();
    ConjuntoTabla aux;
    aux = (ConjuntoTabla)c;
    if (!aux.vacio()) {
        for (int i=0; i<this.nelem(); i++) {
            int n= this.getElem(i);
            if (!aux.pertenece(n)) {
                diferencia.añadir(n);
            }
        }   
    }
    return diferencia;
}

public int nelem() {
    return (_tablaInt.length);
}

public int elem(int i) {
    int n = getElem(i-nelem());
    return n;
}

@Override // Heredado de Object
public String toString() {
String s = "";
for (int i=0; i < nelem(); i++) {
        int n = getElem(i);
        if (i==0) s = s + n;
        else s = s + "," + n;
}
return "[" + s + "]";
}
}

//Interfaz, no puedo modificarla

public interface Conjunto {
// Descripción general: conjunto (concepto matemático) de enteros

public void añadir(int n);
// Pre : ---
// Post: Se ha añadido  n  al conjunto

public boolean pertenece(int n);
// Pre : ---
// Post: Dice si  n  pertenece al conjunto

public boolean vacio();
// Pre : ---
// Post: Dice si el conjunto es vacío

public Conjunto union(Conjunto c);
// Pre : ---
// Post: Devuelve la unión de este conjunto con c

public Conjunto interseccion(Conjunto c);
// Pre : ---
// Post: Devuelve la intersección de este conjunto con c

public Conjunto diferencia(Conjunto c);
// Pre : ---
// Post: Devuelve la diferencia de este conjunto con c

public int nelem();
// Pre : ---
// Post: Dice cuantos elementos tiene el conjunto

public int elem(int i);
// Pre : 1 <= i <= nelem()
// Post: Devuelve el i-éssimo elemento de este conjunto según orden numérico
}

//Programa principal, no puedo modificarlo:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestConjuntoTabla {
// Descripción general: Pequeño test de la clase ConjuntoTabla.
//
// Lee dos secuencias consecutivas de enteros (posiblemente con
// elementos repetidos) separadas por '#', las pone en dos conjuntos,
// y muestra su unión, intersección y diferencia.

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
Conjunto c1 = new ConjuntoTabla();
Conjunto c2 = new ConjuntoTabla();

System.out.println("Introducir dos secuencias de enteros, separadas por el símbolo #");

while (s.hasNextInt())
    c1.añadir(s.nextInt());

s.next(); // Salta '#'

while (s.hasNextInt())
    c2.añadir(s.nextInt());

    System.out.println("\nc1: " + c1);
System.out.println("c2: " + c2);
System.out.println("c1 unión c2: " + c1.union(c2));
System.out.println("c1 intersección c2: " + c1.interseccion(c2));
System.out.println("c1 menos c2: " + c1.diferencia(c2));
}

}
```

Comment: Hola Joel, una consulta, en tu classe ConjuntoTabla , tienes la interfaz, los setters y getters y la logica todo en esa clase o esta dividido por capas?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda en concreto? Si deseas una opinión, entonces este no es el sitio adecuado para eso. Te sugiero que plantees una duda en concreto. Si el programa funciona sin errores, entonces está bien. Ahora, si lo que deseas es modificar un comportamiento, puedes preguntar sobre esa modificación en particular. Si el ejercicio que estás resolviendo es académico, lo mejor es que aclares tus dudas con el tutor, nuestra opinión le puede valer nada al tutor, al fin y al cabo es él quien pone la nota, no somos nosotros. No lo tomes a mal, trato de darte un buen consejo. Saludos.

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, pero no está muy en línea con la política del sitio porque A) son muchas preguntas diferentes y B) varias de las preguntas tienen respuestas muy opinables. Todo eso hace imposible que haya una respuesta "correcta", que es algo que deberían tener todas las preguntas aquí (mira [ask]). En todo caso, te recomiendo que te informes sobre Javadoc, que es el estándar para documentar clases, métodos y atributos.

Comment: Como es que los metodos union, interseccion y diferencia funcionan... esta retornando el nombre del metodo?

Comment: @gbianchi esta retornando el objeto ConjuntoTabla, el problema es que lo tiene nombrado del mismo modo que el metodo, por lo que genera confusion, otra cosa que vi es que el setter nunca se usa en todod el codigo

Comment: Pues @gbianchi tiene razón, creo debiste escoger otros nombres para las variables que defines en cada método, así el código es aún más claro. Pides claridad, empieza por eso.

Comment: no hay una forma mejor de hacer la union que de a un elemento por vez? y si la union tiene elementos repetidos, que pasa con ellos?

Comment: No tenemos la descripcion del problema y no sabemos si se pueden o no admitir elementos repetidos, la union de los elementos al array de enteros es linea O(n) por que recorre cada elemento y lo va añadiendo al array, si no se puedieran aceptar elementos repetidos se podria usar un HashSet con un solo for

Comment: El propósito de los getters y setters es brindar un acceso controlado al estado del objeto desde fuera de la clase. Si nadie desde fuera de la clase necesita acceder al estado, esos métodos están de más. En cuanto a su uso desde dentro de la clase, no tiene sentido poruqe tenés acceso a todo el estado de la clase.

Comment: Guau muchas gracias a todos! Para empezar cambiaré ya el nombre de las variables de las funciones union, intersección y diferencia. @SJuan76 voy a informarme sobre el Javadoc, lo desconocía totalmente. He eliminado el setter, ni me había dado cuenta que no lo usaba.

Comment: @gbianchi un conjunto nunca puede tener elementos repetidos, no viene explicado pues es más bien un concepto matemático que en el programa doy por supuesto que es sabido. El método añadir ya se encarga de ignorar elementos repetidos, lo añadiré en un comentario para clarificarlo.

Comment: @GastónSaillén tanto la interfaz como la clase como el programa main están en 3 archivos .java distintos. Como le comente a gbianchi, los elementos repetidos no están permitidos por propia definición matemática de lo que es un conjunto.  No puedo usar el HashSet  al tratarse de una función de la API de Java (restricciones del ejercicio).